# Queued broadcast delivery on Android 14 - time of delivery

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-14

On Android 14, broadcasts to context-registered receivers are queued while an app is in the background and in a cached state. The broadcasts won't be delivered until the app is brought back to the foreground. Is the time of delivery guaranteed to be **as soon as the app is put into the foreground**, in particular before any activity/fragment lifecycle methods are called (such as `onResume`, or `onCreateView` in case it had been destroyed etc)?

My use case is that my app is registered to receive a broadcast if the screen is turned off, which sets a flag. When the activity is resumed (`onResume`), the flag is checked and a dialog is displayed to ask the user to re-authenticate. However if this "screen off" broadcast was received after the `onResume`, it wouldn't currently trigger re-authentication.

Comment: I don't see that documented anywhere. Your best bet is to test it on an emulator